# How to run a webtest from vnext including Context Parameter

Tags: tfs-2015, webtest, ordered-test

I am trying to create a smoke test for a webserver using a **webtest** and tfs build 2015. I have a **webtest** that uses a **Datasource**(n rows) to run n times. I also have a **Context Parameter** used to configure the test to various web urls. I used an **orderedtest** to contain the **webtest**. I can run the **orderedtest** using the **Visual Studio Test Task**. Unfortunately, I needed to create multiple file copies of each **webtest** and **orderedtest** because I cannot figure out how to pass a **Context Parameter** to an **orderedtest/webtest**.

Comment: Has your question been answered. If not then please [edit] it to add additional details to explain the real problem. If it has been answered then please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer .

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables whose name starts `Test.` are added to the web test as context parameters. If environment variable `Test.Abcd` has the value `efgh` then the context parameter `Abcd` will to be set to `efgh`. See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/edglas/2010/02/16/parameterizing-tests-to-run-in-different-environments/) for more details.